# Remove version on App Store

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I have newly release the second version of my app on App Store. But there is a bug with it.

How can I remove the newest versjon on itunes connect, and go back to the previous one? Namely the first version.

Comment: what is your new version status ? it is waiting for review or ready to sale.

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple, Inc. through iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **Apple doesn't let you remove the current version and go to previous version**. What most of the developers do is we fix the bugs and send an updated version as soon as possible to avoid crashes/errors etc.

The **good news is Apple now reviews your updates quicker** than before. From 8 to 24 hours as opposed to days or even weeks in the past (provided your app follows Apple's guidelines).

Good luck sending out the updated version with the bug fixes! Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's not possible to just "remove" one/the last version. You can only remove the complete app ("Developer Removed From Sale").

I'd suggest that you try to fix the bug and submit a new version (might even be the old one) and request an expedited review.